# Chrome ARC timezone display

Tags: android, google-chrome-arc

I tried my Android app TIDE NOW WA under the Chrome ARC. Worked surprisingly well but there is an odd thing. My app needs the local time to display correct results, this is true in Daylight Savings Time as well as Standard Time.
Under Android, today in DST, my app shows the time zone as "PDT", and the accordingly adjusted time is provided. Under ARC (running Chrome Browser & Windows 7) the time zone is shown as "GMT-07:00"

I get the time from Android like this

runDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // will display tides for this date/time
....

and I determine Daylight Savings Time in effect like this

DST=(runDate.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET)==3600000); // is it Daylight Savings today?

So my app (under ARC) displays incorrectly during Daylight Savings Time but correctly during Standard Time. Is this a bug of my own or is it a feature of ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated arc, to  43.4410.349.9, (latest today) and it fixed it. This was after updating the chrome browser to 43 which by itself did not fix it.

The update fixed my app and now it works just like the phone version. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This problem should already be fixed in 43 (beta channel), and should be promoted to stable soon.

Comment: Thank you, how do I know when it has been fixed and I can try again.

Comment: If your Chrome is version 43+ (currently beta channel, and will be promoted to stable later), the issue should be gone.

Comment: OK I am at 42.something will keep checking. thanks again

Comment: Chrome updated today, to Version 43.0.2357.65 m. I re imported the app through ARC. But the problem is still there. There are actually two problems here. The main on is that the app cannot determine it is daylight savings time for some reason, so the displayed data is one hour off. The other problem is the time display the app shows includes the timezone, on my phone it shows "PDT" but on the Arc'ed version it shows "GMT-07:00".